# forget a BLE device in a iPhone 6 (8.1.3)

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I don't know how to forget a BLE device in my iPhone device.
Going to Settings -> Bluetooth page , I see the list of Devices, but I don't see any option to forget it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BLE devices will appear in one of three cases  -

1. An app has an active connection (the device will be listed under "My devices")
2. An app has a pending connection to a device that has gone out of range (the device will be listed under "Other devices")
3. The device is paired (bonded) (the device will be listed under "My Devices" whether it is currently connected or not)

Only case 3 will give you  the ability to "forget this device" - as "forget this device" really means to remove the encryption keys that were used in the pairing (bonding).

If case 1 or 2 apply then if you kill the app that has the connection/pending connection then the device will be removed from the list.

Comment: Actually, the BLE terminology for case three is "bonded." A BLE central device  and peripheral can be paired by populating the whitelist of hosts to be connected. This allows an auto-connection between the two. If the crypto keys are exchanged, then the two are bonded and the device will appear under "My Devices." Ref "Bluetooth Low Energy" by Robin Heydon, Prentice Hall, 2013

Comment: Thanks - I have updated my answer but left "paired" as this is the commonly understood term even though it isn't technically correct - e.g. the dialog presented to collect the PIN is a "pairing request"

Comment: Walking in on an app which uses paired and bonded interchangeably in comments and variable names to the confusion of those trying to understand the code, I am somewhat pedantic about this right now. :-)

Comment: @CuriousRabbit So what's "pairing" if it's distinct from "bonding"?

Comment: @huggie: In the case of being paired, the application knows about the BLE peripheral and can establish a connection to the device.

In the case of bonding, the devices have exchanged cryptographically secure keys, can communicate securely, and cannot be spoofed unless the key pairs have become compromised.