# Clearing iOS BLE cache

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm currently running on iOS 7. It appears that BLE peripheral device name retrieved during scanning is cached based on the address. Even when the name of the BLE device is flushed with a new value, during iOS 7's peripheral device discovery `[myCentralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];` I get the old device name prior to flushing.

1. Is there a way to programmatically clear the BLE device cache?
2. Even with manual flushing it seems impossible. Under Setting->Bluetooth, BLE device never seems to be listed, despite being able to programmatically scan and connect. (as instructed [here](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/06/11/remove-paired-bluetooth-device-iphone/)) Why is that?

Comment: For the answer to your second question see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28841590/forget-a-ble-device-in-a-iphone-6-8-1-3/28842600#28842600 re the conditions under which a BLE device will be visible in Settings->Bluetooth

Comment: @huggie I'm having the same issue on iOS 8, have you found a solution?

Comment: @Kai No luck. I've always seem to get the same old result and I've not found a way around it.

Comment: @Kai By the way, it seems to be BLE chip dependent. Some chip seems not to have the same problem.

Comment: @huggie I'm using TI 2541 and it definitely has this issue (and then some), do you know which chipsets are not affected? thanks

Comment: @Kai TI 2650 seems to work fine. Your mileage may vary don't count on it.

Comment: @huggie 2650 is more expensive, I don't think I'll be using it any time soon :_(

Comment: Manually turning off Bluetooth cleared the cache for me. I'd assume, then, that programmatically turning Bluetooth off and on might also do the trick, although that wouldn't be the best user experience.

Comment: The only software dependent way to handle it is to connect to the device and handle "peripheralDidUpdateName" event to see if the name has changed. Another (not a very scalable) option (if the peripheral is your own) is to put the name in advertising data.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend one of the most effective and violent solutions
And my approach worked!!!

RESET YOUR IPHONE

Setting --> General --> Erase All Content and Settings

After that and scan again . It worked.

Other way:

Now let me tell you the correct way to solve the issue:

There are 2 names to consider. The advertising name and the GAP (Generic Access Profile) name.

For a peripheral which iOS has never connected before, the 'name' property reported is the advertising name. Once it is connected, the GAP name is cached, and is reported as the peripheral's name. GAP name is considered a "better" name due to the size restrictions on the advertising name.

There is no rule that says both names must match. That depends on your use case and implementation. Some people will consider the GAP name as the fixed name, but the advertising name more of an "alias", as it can easily be changed.

If you want both names in sync, you should change the GAP name as well along with the advertised name. Implemented properly, your CB manager delegate will receive a call to - peripheralDidUpdateName:
If you want to manually clear the cache, you need to reset the iOS device.

link(https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19381)

In fact, this method (peripheralDidUpdateName) is not called

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {

    NSString * gapName = peripheral.name;
    NSString * identityName = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey];
}
```

It is more precisely to use 
[advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey]
to get peripheral name than 
peripheral.name

Because peripheral.name get the GAP name but [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey] get the updated name.

[image: here is the screenshot]

Comment: CSS v7§1.2.1: "The Local Name data type shall be the same as, or a shortened version of, the local name assigned to the device. [...] If the name is shortened, the complete name can be read using the remote name request procedure over BR/EDR or by reading the device name characteristic after the connection has been established using GATT.
A shortened name shall only contain contiguous characters from the beginning of the full name. For example, if the device name is ‘BT_Device_Name’ then the shortened name could be ‘BT_Device’ or ‘BT_Dev’."